# Lightning Web Component findIndex

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, java

Hi I need help with the method that follows:
var ages = [3, 10, 18, 20];

function checkAdult(age) {
return age >= 18;
}

function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ages.findIndex(checkAdult);
}

Comment: didn't get the proper answer

Comment: Please edit your existing post to clarify. Don't repost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's entirely possible that the values are null instead of an empty string. There is a difference between the two (JavaScript actually has both null and undefined types that represent a missing a value). Also, findIndex is not necessary here, you can just use find:

```
const test = !!data.find(value => value.Fname || value.Lname);
```

The !! notation converts a falsy value to false and a truthy value to true without a ternary operator. A value is falsy if it is null, undefined, empty string, 0, or false, and true otherwise. This should be sufficient for your use case.

Also, I noticed a typo in your code, which I've fixed, above. `Lanme` is probably meant to be `Lname`. Pay attention to typos, as that can easily cause hard-to-detect problems in JavaScript.

Comment: actually in the org if field value is blank then it is not present in the data aray.

Comment: @raman That would be `undefined`, not `''`.

Comment: const test = !data.some(value => !(value.Fname || value.Lname));

@raman try this.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thnakyou soo much it is undefined!! eaten my head from 1 hour